# Output of XML in Resultset (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a XML file and I want to create a SELECT statement with a specific output.

```
<Errors>
  <Error CheckNumber="5" Message="Within the unit there are identifier duplicates.">
    <ProductionInfo ProductionOrderNo="ABC12345" >
      <Identifier>
        <RawID>67484295</RawID>
        <UnitCode>.gEft?s</UnitCode>
        <UnitGTIN>1234567890</UnitGTIN>
      </Identifier>
      <Identifier>
        <RawID>67484297</RawID>
        <UnitCode>_Yo*IpH</UnitCode>
        <UnitGTIN>1234567890</UnitGTIN>
      </Identifier>
      <Identifier>
        <RawID>67484301</RawID>
        <UnitCode>3IBIsik</UnitCode>
        <UnitGTIN>1234567890</UnitGTIN>
      </Identifier>
      <Identifier>
        <RawID>67484318</RawID>
        <UnitCode>g&lt;*fnh6</UnitCode>
        <UnitGTIN>1234567890</UnitGTIN>
      </Identifier>
      <Identifier>
        <RawID>67484326</RawID>
        <UnitCode>LI?jTW/</UnitCode>
        <UnitGTIN>1234567890</UnitGTIN>
      </Identifier>
    </ProductionInfo>
  </Error>
  <Error CheckNumber="6" Message="The unit does not contain the required number of content information.">
    <ProductionInfo ProductionOrderNo="ABC12345" ProductionLine_InternalNo="11204">
      <Identifier>
        <RawID>67484295</RawID>
        <UnitCode>.gEft?s</UnitCode>
        <UnitGTIN>1234567890</UnitGTIN>
      </Identifier>
      <Identifier>
        <RawID>67484297</RawID>
        <UnitCode>_Yo*IpH</UnitCode>
        <UnitGTIN>1234567890</UnitGTIN>
      </Identifier>
  </ProductionInfo>
  </Error>
</Errors>
```

What I want is a output of two columns (ErrorMessage & Identifier). The Identifier-Column should be a character separated list of the underlying identifier.

So the output in my example should (in my example the separator is the '@') have 2 lines like:

[Example image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYJ6I.png).

How will the final SELECT look like, to get this output?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `query` to select the node attribute and elements.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (ErrorsValues XML)
INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT '
<Errors>
  <Error CheckNumber="5" Message="Within the unit there are identifier duplicates.">
    <ProductionInfo ProductionOrderNo="ABC12345" >
      <Identifier>
        <RawID>67484295</RawID>
        <UnitCode>.gEft?s</UnitCode>
        <UnitGTIN>1234567890</UnitGTIN>
      </Identifier>
      <Identifier>
        <RawID>67484297</RawID>
        <UnitCode>_Yo*IpH</UnitCode>
        <UnitGTIN>1234567890</UnitGTIN>
      </Identifier>
      <Identifier>
        <RawID>67484301</RawID>
        <UnitCode>3IBIsik</UnitCode>
        <UnitGTIN>1234567890</UnitGTIN>
      </Identifier>
      <Identifier>
        <RawID>67484318</RawID>
        <UnitCode>g&lt;*fnh6</UnitCode>
        <UnitGTIN>1234567890</UnitGTIN>
      </Identifier>
      <Identifier>
        <RawID>67484326</RawID>
        <UnitCode>LI?jTW/</UnitCode>
        <UnitGTIN>1234567890</UnitGTIN>
      </Identifier>
    </ProductionInfo>
  </Error>
  <Error CheckNumber="6" Message="The unit does not contain the required number of content information.">
    <ProductionInfo ProductionOrderNo="ABC12345" ProductionLine_InternalNo="11204">
      <Identifier>
        <RawID>67484295</RawID>
        <UnitCode>.gEft?s</UnitCode>
        <UnitGTIN>1234567890</UnitGTIN>
      </Identifier>
      <Identifier>
        <RawID>67484297</RawID>
        <UnitCode>_Yo*IpH</UnitCode>
        <UnitGTIN>1234567890</UnitGTIN>
      </Identifier>
  </ProductionInfo>
    </Error>
</Errors>'
```

--The query

```
select y.value('@Message','varchar(300)') as ErrorMessage
      ,y.query('data(ProductionInfo/Identifier/UnitCode)')
        .value('.','nvarchar(max)') as Identifier 
from @temp  t
cross apply ErrorsValues.nodes('Errors/Error') x(y);
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: @nicetomitja This answer points the right direction but has some flaws: Use `y.value('@Message','varchar(300)') as ErrorMessage` in order to get correct results. Using `.query()` with `CAST()` would not re-escape entities (e.g. `&amp; => "&"`). Furthermore, use `y.query('data(ProductionInfo/Identifier/UnitCode)').value('.','nvarchar(max)') as Identifier` for the same reason. And last but not least: XQuery's  `data()` will always use a blank as delimiter. If your Identifiers might contain blanks, this might not work correctly...

Comment: @Shnugo The solution to your final issue is to use `/text()` not `data()`, as edited

Comment: @Charlieface, No, your edit broke the requirements (*The Identifier-Column should be a character separated list of the underlying identifier*) Using your approach will glue all parts directly, while `data()` returns them with a blank in between. Tiny, but important. If the content can contain a blank there is a way using `FLWOR`-query with XQuery's `concat()` and a `STUFF()` at the end. But - as the OP accepted - blanks seem to be okay.